# Trying to print state assosciated with max value

Tags: python, csv

I have finally figured out the code to find the max value of a CSV file. 
However, I now need to print the state name associated with the max value. 
Heres the CSV file for reference: [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29hT1HI-pwxTnVIM00xSUMwNjg)

I feel as though there is an extremely simple way to just print out the the state name associated with the max value (California). I was thinking answer[4] or something... please no libraries. We are limited to import CSV for this project.

```
def largestState():
    with open('state-populations.csv', 'rU') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader) # Skip header row
        next(reader) #Skip United States row 
        answer = max(int(column[5].replace(',', '')) for column in reader)
    print answer

largestState()
```

Comment: This is the third question you've asked about this today. Have you made any independent progress?

Comment: you can store the CSV as an array and `sort()` it for all the information you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `key` argument to `max`, and iterate through the entire row.

```
In [2]: def largest_state():
   ...:     with open('state-populations (1).csv') as f:
   ...:         reader = csv.reader(f)
   ...:         next(reader)
   ...:         next(reader)
   ...:         answer = max(reader, key=lambda r: int(r[5].replace(',','')))
   ...:         print(answer[4])
   ...:
   ...:

In [3]: largest_state()
California
```

Comment: Thank you! clear and concise, just what i needed. you are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473808/csv-find-max-in-column-and-append-new-data).
One improvement on juanpa.arrivillaga's answer:

```
def largestState():
    with open('state-populations.csv', 'rU') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader) # Skip header row
        next(reader) #Skip United States row
        answer = max(reader, key=lambda col: int(col[5].replace(',', '')))
    print answer[4],answer[5]

largestState()
```

The first parameter of max can be an iterator directly.

The output would be: `California 38332521`

Comment: yes, you are correct. that was a silly mistake

Comment: thank you. more often than not people ask the same question as me but i can never find it on google!